# Deploy website based x32 on OS x64 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, deployment, web, compatibility, 32bit-64bit

I have **website** with Oracle Data Access Components created on OS x32, all dependencies was compiled on OS x32.

Now i have a new OS x64, when i try to deploy the website,  compiles good with plataform "Debug|Any CPU", but it shows me many errors that may be related to plataform target in the index.

What i've tried?:

1. Uncheck "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects" in the Projects and Solutions Menu
2. I guess I can not change the Plataform of the project from "Any CPU" to "x86" because it is related to a website, so, don't need use any cpu to compile.
3. Compile the .sln with devenv via console with /Build "Debug|x86" configuration.
4. I tried put compilerOptions="/platform:x86" on the web.config

Nothing has a result.

How could I solve?

1. Can i convert all the website with all dependencies to x64 project?.
2. Need i do something related to oracle data access to have compatibility? for example install again the drivers with specifically configurations?

Thanks!!!